# How to fix the error "Wrong number of arguments to function rank()" on SQLite Android using FTS4?

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, android-room, fts4

I have two tables:

- `persons`
- `persons_fts`.

Here are the definitions of the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE persons(name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, details TEXT);

CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE persons_fts USING FTS4(name TEXT NOT NULL, details TEXT, context=persons);
```

I want to do a full-text-search with a query on the `persons_fts` table, and rank the results on the basis of relevance. After looking at the [official docs](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#appendix_a) on how to do this, I ended with the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM persons
JOIN persons_fts ON persons.name = persons_fts.name
WHERE persons_fts MATCH :query
ORDER BY rank(matchinfo(persons_fts)) DESC;
```

Besides the extra join, this query is the exact same as the one outlined in the official docs. However, I get an error when I try to execute it:

> Error retrieving data from the table: Wrong number of arguments to function rank() (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

What am I doing wrong?

Please note that using FTS5 is not an option for me.

Comment: `rank()` is a window function that takes no arguments. Not sure what you're trying to do with it here...

Comment: Ah, I see what you're looking at in the fts3 documentation. Read the comments in that query carefully.

Comment: @Shawn If you could point me to the docs for FTS4, that would be great. As far as i know, the page I linked in the question is the documentation for both FTS3 and FTS4.

Comment: That is the documentation, yes.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. I didn't realize that `rank` didn't ship with SQLite, and was instead a user defined function. I have added an answer below which accomplishes the same thing as the example in the official docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked SQLite documentation in the question clarifies what the `rank` function does in the comments above the query it is used in:

> If the application supplies an SQLite user function called "rank" that interprets the blob of data returned by matchinfo and returns a numeric relevancy based on it, then the following SQL may be used to return the titles of the 10 most relevant documents in the dataset for a users query.

`rank` is expected to be a user supplied function. It does not ship with SQLite.

Here's an implementation of the `rank` function in Kotlin which calculates the relevance score on the basis of the data supplied by `matchinfo` using the default "pcx" argument:

```kotlin
fun rank(matchInfo: IntArray): Double {
  val numPhrases = matchInfo[0]
  val numColumns = matchInfo[1]

  var score = 0.0
  for (phrase in 0 until numPhrases) {
    val offset = 2 + phrase * numColumns * 3
    for (column in 0 until numColumns) {
      val numHitsInRow = matchInfo[offset + 3 * column]
      val numHitsInAllRows = matchInfo[offset + 3 * column + 1]
      if (numHitsInAllRows > 0) {
        score += numHitsInRow.toDouble() / numHitsInAllRows.toDouble()
      }
    }
  }

  return score
}
```

To understand how this code works, you should go through the [`rankfunc` example](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#appendix_a) given in the official docs.

Since our rank function is a Kotlin function, it can not be used directly by SQLite. Instead, we will need to first retrieve the `matchinfo` blob from the database, and then pass it to our rank function.

Here's an example on how to do it with Room:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface PersonsDao {
  
  @Query("""
    SELECT *, matchinfo(persons_fts, 'pcx') as mi
    FROM persons
    JOIN persons_fts ON persons.name = persons_fts.name
    WHERE persons_fts MATCH :query
  """)
  suspend fun search(query: String): List<PersonWithMatchInfo>
}

data class PersonWithMatchInfo(
  @Embedded
  val person: Person
  @ColumnInfo(name = "mi")
  val matchInfo: ByteArray
)
```

The retrieved `ByteArray` contains a sequence of numbers representing the match info, in which each number is represented by 4 bytes. The first byte is the actual value, and the next three bytes are zero. Therefore we need to remove the redundant zeroes before passing this ByteArray to `rank`. This can be done with a simple method:

```kotlin
fun ByteArray.skip(skipSize: Int): IntArray {
  val cleanedArr = IntArray(this.size / skipSize)
  var pointer = 0
  for (i in this.indices step skipSize) {
    cleanedArr[pointer] = this[i].toInt()
    pointer++
  }

  return cleanedArr
}
```

This setup can be used like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun searchWithRanks(query: String): List<Person> {
  return personDao.search(query)
        .sortedByDescending { result -> rank(result.matchInfo.skip(4)) }
        .map { result -> result.person }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! I believe it could be improved in 2 ways:
1) by using Kotlin standard lib SLICE(indices step 4) function instead of custom SKIP(4) extension;
2) by adding list of columns weights and multiplying score by them.